# Django queryset in view isn't returning anything to the html template

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset, django-listview

I want to show all posts of a specific user in their profile page but only their profile information is being displayed but not the posts.

My initial code was simply trying to loop through the posts in the template like this:

```
      {% for post in user.posts.all %}
      {% endfor %}
```

But it didn't work. So I tried this next.

views.py

```
     user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
     post = Post.objects.filter(created_by=user.id)

     context = {
          'user': user,
          'post': post
     }

     return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)
```

profile.html

```
<div class="user-profile">
    <img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}">
    {{ user.username }}
    {{ user.email }}
</div>

<div class="user-post-model">
{% for post in posts %}
   <img class="rounded-circle post-img" src="{{ post.created_by.profile.image.url }}">
   {{ post.title }}
   {{ post.content|safe }}
   {{post.tag}}
   {{ post.created_by }}
   {{ post.created_at|naturaltime}}
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

It didn't work either

I also tried using a ListView to post the posts. It worked but instead of showing the specific user's profile information it showed the logged in user's profile information but the specific user's posts.

like this:

```
def profile(request, username):
     user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)

     context = {
          'user': user
     }

     return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)

class UserPostListView(ListView):
     model = Post
     template_name = 'users/profile.html'
     context_object_name = 'posts'
     
     def get_queryset(self):
          user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
          return Post.objects.filter(created_by=user).order_by('-created_at')
```

This is the post model

```
class Post(models.Model):
     title =  models.CharField(max_length=255)
     content = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=30000)
     created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
     created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     tag =  models.CharField(max_length=255, default='uncategorised')

     class Meta:
          ordering = ('-created_at',)

     def __str__(self):
          return self.title + ' | ' + str(self.created_by)

     def get_absolute_url(self):
          return reverse("post-detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

What is wrong?

Comment: `{% for post in posts %}` in the context you have passed `post` yet you loop over `posts`

Comment: Did you try just using `request.user`?

Comment: Even if I type `{% for post in post %}` which I had tried before, it won't loop throught the posts.

Comment: `request.user` also does not return anything @M-Chen-3

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I want the posts of a specific user, not just for the logged in user. Much like viewing someones profile/account page for Youtube\instagram. It should return the posts for the account only. `request.user` only give mes the logged in user,s information when I click on someone's account.

Comment: @ImmortalNoob you never pass the user in the context for the `ListView` so it uses the user passed into the context by the default context processors which is the current logged in user. You should override `get_context_data` and pass the user into the context from there.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat `def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
                              context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
                         user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
          context['post'] = Post.objects.filter(created_by=user).order_by('-created_at')
          return context ` I used this code instead. I don't think I implemented it correctly. It didn'w work.

Comment: @ImmortalNoob, Share also the `Post` model.

Comment: @NKSM I have added the post model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To loop over the related `Post` objects to `User`, use [**`_set`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#related-objects-reference) ([Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#related-objects-reference)).

So in your case `user.post_set`:

```
{% for post in user.post_set.all %}
    {{ post.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: @ImmortalNoob, Happy to help))) and success in coding.